# Frequency distribution after lemmatize and removal of stop words

Tags: python, nltk

I need to read a file [mbox.txt](http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox.txt) and find its word frequency distribution  using `nltk.FreqDist()`, then return a list of ten most frequent words. However, I need to first:

1. Lemmatize words
2. remove stop words
3. Keep only English terms
4. Keep only terms that belong to the Ten most frequent parts of speech.

The sample output is:

```
[('received', 16176), ('id', 12609), ('source', 10792), ('tue', 4498), ('mon', 3686), ('date', 3612), ('sakai', 3611), ('murder', 3594), ('cyrus', 3594), ('postfix', 3594)]
```

The code I have written is

```
import nltk, re
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import word_tokenize

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(open('mbox.txt').read())

lmtzr = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatized = [[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in word_tokenize(t)]
              for t in tokens]

fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
fdist1.most_common(10)
```

and the output I have is:

`[(':', 67406),  ('--', 43761),  (')', 40168),  ('(', 40160),  ('2007', 22447),  ('@', 22019), (';', 21582),  (',', 18632),  ('from', 16328), ('by', 16231)]`

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What is `lemmatized` used for after its processing?

Comment: I am thinking that lemmatize will group together the different inflected forms of a word so they can be analysed as a single item? That is also requirement 1 of the exercise question.

Comment: Special characters are causing the problems, as they are used a lot of time in the given corpus.
Add these special chars(:, --, (, ), @, ;, ) to your stopwords. Also, remove digits using some regex pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not removing stop words and non-english terms
2. You are checking FreqDict for tokens, not lemmas

Try this code:

```
import nltk, re
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Regex for only english terms (with dots)
ENGLISH_RE = re.compile(r'[a-z]+')

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(open('mbox').read())

lmtzr = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
# Save the list between tokens
lemmatized = []
for word in tokens:
    # Lowerize for correct use in stopwords etc
    w = word.lower()
    # Check english terms
    if not ENGLISH_RE.match(w):
        continue
    # Check stopwords
    if w in stopwords.words('english'):
        continue
    lemmatized.append(lmtzr.lemmatize(w))

fdist1 = nltk.FreqDist(lemmatized)
fdist1.most_common(10)
```